# Как правильно сделать флексы

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Мне нужно сделать пункт меню. В идеале что-то такое, 34px height:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иконка и текст "сегодня" внутри на флексах. Если я задаю блоку inner внутренний отступ, то начинает растягиваться весь блок project, а мне это не нужно. Я могу добавить внешний отступ блоку inner, но я хочу задать padding родительскому блоку, а не дочернему margin. Как мне отцентровать это всё и сделать грамотно через padding? + как исправить svg-иконку, если вставлять через img всё работает нормально

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .project {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            left: 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 240px;
            height: 34px;

            /* Из-за этого растягивается */
            padding: 5px;

            background: #E1E3E7;
        }

        .project__title {
            color: #393D41;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        .project__icon {
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .project__inner {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="project">
      <div class="project__inner">
          <span class="project__icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24"><path d="M9 42q-1.2 0-2.1-.9Q6 40.2 6 39V9q0-1.2.9-2.1Q7.8 6 9 6h30q1.2 0 2.1.9.9.9.9 2.1v30q0 1.2-.9 2.1-.9.9-2.1.9Zm0-3h30v-6.8h-7.3q-1.3 2-3.375 3.075Q26.25 36.35 24 36.35t-4.325-1.075Q17.6 34.2 16.3 32.2H9V39Zm15-5.65q2.05 0 3.7-1.175Q29.35 31 30.5 29.2H39V9H9v20.2h8.5q1.15 1.8 2.8 2.975T24 33.35ZM9 39h30Z"/></svg>
          </span>
          <span class="project__title">Inbox</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в svg явно не так

Вам так нужно?

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.project {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #E1E3E7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.project__title {
  color: #393D41;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.project__icon {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.project__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <div class="project__inner">
    <span class="project__icon">
<svg class='svg' width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="17" height="17" rx="1.5" stroke="#05A750"/>
<path d="M8.18066 15H3.48828V14.3018L5.36816 12.4121C5.94108 11.8327 6.31868 11.4193 6.50098 11.1719C6.68327 10.9245 6.81999 10.6836 6.91113 10.4492C7.00228 10.2148 7.04785 9.96257 7.04785 9.69238C7.04785 9.31152 6.93229 9.01042 6.70117 8.78906C6.47005 8.56445 6.14941 8.45215 5.73926 8.45215C5.44303 8.45215 5.16146 8.50098 4.89453 8.59863C4.63086 8.69629 4.33626 8.8737 4.01074 9.13086L3.58105 8.5791C4.23861 8.03223 4.95475 7.75879 5.72949 7.75879C6.40007 7.75879 6.92578 7.93132 7.30664 8.27637C7.6875 8.61816 7.87793 9.07878 7.87793 9.6582C7.87793 10.1107 7.75098 10.5583 7.49707 11.001C7.24316 11.4437 6.7679 12.0036 6.07129 12.6807L4.50879 14.209V14.248H8.18066V15ZM10.1143 15L13.0732 8.6084H9.18164V7.86133H13.9326V8.51074L11.0127 15H10.1143Z" fill="#05A750"/>
<rect x="3" y="5" width="12" height="1" fill="#05A750"/>
</svg>
          </span>
    <span class="project__title">Сегодня</span>
  </div>
</div>
```